# Retrieve info for specific user's ID

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I do my PHD work dedicated to Social Network Analysis.
As tools was selected Node JS and Facebook API
Now what I can do is retrieve user's ID's with the additional info, but to build graph I need lists of the user's friends. 
I have Heroku App but I'm totally disappointed what to do with te APP_ID to get information needed to build data.
Where I should start?

Answer (score 0):

There are some Node.js packages available for this purpose.

[Third party SDKs for Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/third-party-sdks/#nodejs)

[This](https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk) is very useful, in case you want to write the same code and share between your server (nodejs) and the client ([FB JS-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/))

In order to start, you need to have access_tokens from users, you want information from. (Through FB App)

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        var res = response.authResponse;
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          registerUser({ "fb_user_id": res.userID,      //register user in your database
                         "access_token": res.accessToken
                       }, function() {
              //handle here after registration
          });
        });
    } else {
        //handle reject in requested fields
    }
},  { scope: 'email,friends_about_me'});
//you can set scope field according to your use.
```

Refer to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/) for extended profile properties that can be used in scope field.

Once you get access_tokens, you can use them with one of the third party SDK above.

For example with [facebook-node-sdk](https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk),

This sdk also provides you request access_token api

```
var FB = require('fb');
var accessToken = FB.getAccessToken();
FB.setAccessToken(accessToken);

FB.api('idHere', { fields: ['id', 'name'] }, function (res) {     //you can access fields, access_token has access to
  if(!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(res.id);
  console.log(res.name);
});
```

You can also use `api function` directly with access_token.

```
FB.api('me', { fields: ['id', 'name'], access_token: 'access_token' }, function (res) {
    console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That example allow us get public info i already have. But get list of friends I must have access_token. How to get this token?